# Stateless component in React and "Props is defined but never used" ESLint error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

How can I avoid this error in ESLint? Should I write this code in a different way? I can't change ESLint config and I should have 0 errors...

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './style.css';

import SearchBar from '../SearchBar';
import GithubDataTable from '../GithubDataTable';

const App = props => (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">The Task</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
      <SearchBar />
      <GithubDataTable />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `props` at all.

You can just write it like a function without params:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './style.css';

import SearchBar from '../SearchBar';
import GithubDataTable from '../GithubDataTable';

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">
      <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
      <h1 className="App-title">The Task</h1>
    </header>
    <div>
      <SearchBar />
      <GithubDataTable />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

Comment: Wow, This is great! I didn't know that! I will accept your answer in 10 minutes because I can't do it sooner!